# Git log and graph show different results after git rebase with merge commits

Tags: git, rebase

#### Setup

I have a scenario, as shown by the git log graph below.

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   1c3ae5de (HEAD -> feature) Merge feature-2 into feature
|\
| * 9051a8b8 (feature-2) Commit D
|/
*   940c88e0 Merge feature-1 into feature
|\
| * 60dca27d (feature-1) Commit C
|/
* 8781f253 (main) Commit B
* 8704354e Initial commit
```

As you can hopefully see, there was a `main` branch which branched into the `feature` branch. On the `feature` branch, two separate branches `feature-1` and `feature-2` were branched off, work performed, and merged back into the `feature` branch with a merge commit.

The git log of this scenario is shown below as well.

```
$ git log --oneline
1c3ae5de (HEAD -> feature) Merge feature-2 into feature
9051a8b8 (feature-2) Commit D
940c88e0 Merge feature-1 into feature
60dca27d (feature-1) Commit C
8781f253 (main) Commit B
8704354e Initial commit
```

#### Issue

Now, someone commits a new commit on `main` and suddenly the log graph looks like the following<sup>1</sup>.

```
* 8a16a716 (HEAD -> main) Commit E
| *   1c3ae5de (feature) Merge feature-2 into feature
| |\
| | * 9051a8b8 (feature-2) Commit D
| |/
| * 940c88e0 Merge feature-1 into feature
|/|
| * 60dca27d (feature-1) Commit C
|/
* 8781f253 Commit B
* 8704354e Initial commit
```

What I would like to do is rebase the `feature` branch off of `main`, and preserve merge commits. This is achieved by executing `git rebase --rebase-merges main` while on the `feature` branch. However, after performing this action, the output of `git log --oneline` and `git log --oneline --graph` do not agree in terms of the order of the commits.

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   24e18500 (HEAD -> feature) Merge feature-2 into feature
|\
| * 33da98a4 Commit D
|/
*   a1ce7cd3 Merge feature-1 into feature
|\
| * bd23945b Commit C
|/
* 8a16a716 (main) Commit E
* 8781f253 Commit B
* 8704354e Initial commit
```

```
$ git log --oneline
24e18500 (HEAD -> feature) Merge feature-2 into feature
a1ce7cd3 Merge feature-1 into feature
33da98a4 Commit D
bd23945b Commit C
8a16a716 (main) Commit E
8781f253 Commit B
8704354e Initial commit
```

#### Question

Why does the output of `git log --online` show all the merge commits at the top of the list after a `git rebase --rebase-merges`? And why does that order disagree with the output in graph form?

<sub><sup>1</sup> As an ancillary question, I don't understand why the graph shows a `/` from the main line branch to the `940c88e0` commit. If anyone could answer that as well, I'd be much appreciative.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that `git log` *must* **sort** commits in some cases.

Remember that `git log` is displaying one commit at a time.  Meanwhile, *history*, in a Git repository, consists of the commits themselves and their connections.  For instance, in the initial graph output:

```
*   1c3ae5de (HEAD -> feature) Merge feature-2 into feature
|\
| * 9051a8b8 (feature-2) Commit D
|/
*   940c88e0 Merge feature-1 into feature
|\
| * 60dca27d (feature-1) Commit C
|/
* 8781f253 (main) Commit B
* 8704354e Initial commit
```

commit `1c3ae5de` has two parent commits `940c88e0` (first parent) and `9051a8b8` (second parent) respectively.  Commit `9051a8b8` has just *one* parent, `940c88e0`.  This pattern repeats a bit and when we get to `8781f253` (at the tip of `main`), that commit has one parent `8704354e` and commit `8704354e` has *no* parents.

When we have no merge commits at all—just a simple linear chain of commits—we have a nice simple picture:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--latest
```

The branch name, here `latest`, helps Git find commit `H` quickly.  Commit `H` provides, via the commit object, a snapshot (an archive of all files) and metadata, and the metadata for commit `H` list the author and date and log message and so on, but also list the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  This allows Git to use `H` to *find* `G`.

Commit `G` is of course a commit, and as such has both snapshot and metadata.  The metadata for `G` lists earlier commit `F`'s raw hash ID, which allows Git to use `G` to find `F`.  Commit `F`, being a commit, has snapshot and metadata, and onwards (or backwards) we (or Git) go(es).  Eventually we reach the very first commit, which—being first—has an empty list of previous commits and therefore Git gets to stop going backwards.

For `git log` to do its job—show (some) commits—we tell Git log which commit(s) we wish it to *start* with, via command line arguments:

```
git log main
```

or:

```
git log feature
```

for instance, or we let it default to starting with `HEAD`, or we use `--all` or `--branches` or something to select more than one starting point, or we can even give `git log` multiple raw hash IDs (though of course we probably have to run `git log` first to get them ).

We can also use options (e.g., `--no-merges` or `--max-parents=1`, which mean the same thing) to prevent *showing* certain commits, and more options (e.g., `--first-parent`) to modify *how* `git log` follows commits backwards.  For the moment, though, let's assume we're not doing any of this: we're having `git log` show every commit it visits, during this backwards walk, and not directing it to skip parts of the graph.

As long as we're letting `git log` start with *one* commit (and not modifying the graph-walk), that's the commit it shows first.  Having shown that commit, `git log` moves backwards to its parent (singular—there's trouble ahead but let's not get there yet) and shows that one.  Having shown the parent, `git log` moves backwards one step yet again, and so on.  That defines the order in which we see the commits: one at a time, backwards, along this simple linear chain.

But: what if we tell `git log` to show *two* commits, say, `60dca27d` *and* `9051a8b8`, via `git log feature-1 feature-2`?  Now `git log` has *two* commits to show initially.  What *order* should it use to show them?

While—or maybe before—we think too hard about that one, let's consider a branch-y history like yours only different:

```
     C--D
    /    \
A--B      G--H   <-- main
    \    /
     E--F
```

There's only one obvious place to start—from branch name `main` which selects commit `H`—so we'll have `git log` start there and work backwards, to commit `G`.  But commit `G` is a *merge commit*, whose very definition is that it has two or more parents.<sup>1</sup>  Which one should `git log` visit *first?*  And if we pick either `D` or `F` first, which one should `git log` visit *second?*  Should it keep going down that "leg" of the merge, or should it switch to the other "leg", or what?

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls a merge commit with more than two parents an *octopus merge*, which is why the logo for GitHub is [the octocat](https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/583231?v=4).

---

#### Git's answer to the order dilemma

There are a lot of ways to handle this, but Git's is ... complicated.  There are sorting options, and filtering options as well, and all of them work based off a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) algorithm.  The actual log-walk goes like this:

1. Create an empty queue.
2. Insert, into the queue, in priority order, all commits named on the command line.
3. While the queue is not empty:

   1. Take the highest priority item *off* the queue and visit it (optionally showing it).
   2. Insert all or selected parents into the queue, provided they have not been visited before.

So it's the priority *in* the queue that determines which commits we see when.  As long as the queue itself has just *one* commit in it, we see that one commit, and then insert its parent(s) into the now-empty queue.  As long as that one commit has one parent, we get the simple linear walk.

The choice of priority is where `git log`'s sorting options enter this picture.  The first thing to note about it is that the *default* is a commit-date sort order, but `--graph` implies `--topo-order`, which [the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) tells us means:

> Show no parents before all of its children are shown, and avoid showing commits on multiple lines of history intermixed.

So with `--topo-order` and the graph I drew, we'll see `H`, then `G`, then one of `D` or `F`, then the parent of whichever we just saw, then the *other* of `D` or `F`, then the parent of that commit, and only then can `git log` visit commit `B`, after which only commit `A` is in the queue.

*Without* `--topo-order`, Git uses the *committer date* of each commit while working through the fork in the graph that occurs when we move backwards through the merge commit.  The committer date is renewed during a `git rebase`, but the granularity of these time stamps is only one second, so an automated rebase often has a tie.<sup>2</sup>  *With* `--topo-order`, though, the priority will force one entire leg of the merge to be emitted before the other leg is started.  There's no real promise about which leg comes first here, but the *current* `--graph` code itself depends on second-parent coming first, I think.

---

<sup>2</sup>The tie will be broken by some unspecified means.  It depends on how whoever wrote the priority queue chose to insert equal-priority items.  Right now, this will at least be deterministic, but some future Git version that uses multiple CPUs in parallel might produce timing-dependent ordering.

---

#### That answers your first question

The `--graph` option forces `--topo-order` which forces a different commit order output.  Any time you have a complex graph, I recommend using `--graph` (or a graphical viewer).  Note that *other* software authors, e.g., `gitk` or other GUIs, may use their own (different) sorting methods for drawing the graph.  As long as they draw a *correct* graph that you can interpret correctly, this isn't all that important.

#### Your second question

> [After] executing `git rebase --rebase-merges main` while on the feature branch [the graph is]

```
* 8a16a716 (HEAD -> main) Commit E
| *   1c3ae5de (feature) Merge feature-2 into feature
| |\
| | * 9051a8b8 (feature-2) Commit D
| |/
| * 940c88e0 Merge feature-1 into feature
|/|
| * 60dca27d (feature-1) Commit C
|/
* 8781f253 Commit B
* 8704354e Initial commit
```

> ... why [does] the graph show a `/` from the main line branch to the `940c88e0` commit

It doesn't.  It shows that going from commit `940c88e0` back *to* the `main` line.  The second parent of `940c88e0` is `8781f253`, which is your `Commit B`.  It also shows that going from `9051a8b8` to its (first and only) parent.  In particular though, there is **no connection** from commit `8a16a716` (on `main`) back to these commits: there's only a straight-line connection down to `8781f253`.

The positions and directions of the markers (`|`, `\`, and `/`) in `git log --graph` output are significant: at a merge commit we always see one line with `*` and then one line with `|\` or `/|` underneath.  (I think `git log --graph` used to use `|\` always, and then reverse the `\`, but I might be mis-remembering.)

The *vertical* line marks the connection to the *first* parent.  The *diagonal* line, `\` or `/`, marks the connection to the *second* parent (and for octopus merges, to additional parents as needed).  The reason this matters is ... well, first, let's back up a bit and say that sometimes it *does not* matter.

When you run `git merge` you do so by:

- checking out some particular commit, so that it is now `HEAD` (and you're on that branch, assuming you use a branch name to get here); then
- running `git merge other` or similar, where *`other`* specifies the other branch-tip commit.

The `git rebase --rebase-merges` code is no different here.  Rebase copies ordinary non-merge commits using `git cherry-pick`, but literally *re-runs* `git merge` to *re-perform* the merges.<sup>3</sup>  So these merges also first switch to *some* branch, then do the merge.

We know how Git merges actually work:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Here, we're `on branch br1` when we run `git merge br2`.  So Git:

- locates the merge base commit: the best commit on *both* branches is commit `H` in this case;
- in effect, runs two `git diff`s, from merge base to each branch tip;
- combines the diff results to get the set of changes to apply to the snapshot in the merge base;
- applies the combined changes to that snapshot to get the merge snapshot; and
- makes a new merge commit `M`:

  ```
            I--J
           /    \
  ...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
           \    /
            K--L   <-- br2
  ```

As usual, making a new commit causes the current branch name to *point to* the new commit, so `br1` now selects merge commit `M`.  The snapshot for `M` holds the snapshot made by merging the two diffs and applying that to the snapshot from `H`.  The two parents are commits `J` and `L`.  It *won't matter which order we used* when combining those diffs (*unless* we added `-X ours` or `-X theirs` or used `-s ours`, that is!), so does it matter which parent is the *first* parent?

Well, `git log` has `--first-parent`, which tells it that, during the walk through the graph, Git should only add the *first* parent to the priority queue.  So *if we'll use this option later* (will we?), then suddenly it *will* matter which parent is the *first* parent.

We're *guaranteed* that the *first* parent of any merge will be the commit we were "on", from the branch we were "on".  That is, the parent of `M` will definitely be `J`, because we were (and still are) `on branch br1` and its tip was `J` before the merge action.

So `|` tells us which parent was the "main line of development" and `\` or `/` tells us which parent was the other commit.  That side branch will be omitted from the log output entirely if we use `--first-parent`.

---

<sup>3</sup>This is important if you've used `-s ours` or `-X ours` or `-X theirs`, for instance.  Git *does not remember the options used* and will re-perform the merge *without using those options*.  Be careful with `--rebase-merges`!  The documentation will no doubt be updated if and when this changes, but right now it says, in part:

> By default, the merge command will use the `ort` merge strategy for regular merges, and `octopus` for octopus merges. One can specify a default strategy for all merges using the `--strategy` argument when invoking rebase, or can override specific merges in the interactive list of commands by using an `exec` command to call `git merge` explicitly with a `--strategy` argument.

The details are a bit messy and have already evolved from the time `--rebase-merges` was first introduced, so be sure to consult the documentation frequently.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed response! I learned so much more about how git log actually works in more complicated scenarios.

Comment: "The committer date is renewed during a git rebase, but the granularity of these time stamps is only one second, so an automated rebase often has a tie" This would make for a nice TLDR. the timestamp granularity is the important bit.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the output of git log --online show all the merge commits at the top of the list after a git rebase --rebase-merges? And why does that order disagree with the output in graph form?

Well, that's why `--graph` is sometimes a better choice. Without it, the order of the commits is somewhat arbitrary, because a single column is incapable of describing the *topology*.

A merge commit, by definition, has (at least) *two parents*. So if you are going to write the commits in a single column, it is unclear what order to list those parents in, and then, when one of those parents is itself a merge commit, it is even more unclear what order to list *its* parents in, and in what relationship to the first set of parents.

Git can somewhat resolve this dilemma by adhering to an order rule, either `--topo-order` or `--date-order`. You might try playing with adding one of those to your `git log` command to see if you like the resulting order better than what you're getting.

But basically, the answer to your question is: don't worry about it. `--graph` does exist, so if you want a decent look at the real situation and its topology, use it. A full fledged drawing tool, such as `gitk` or a GUI, might give you an even better rendering.

---

The limitations and quirks of `--graph` also explain the difference between

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   1c3ae5de (HEAD -> feature) Merge feature-2 into feature
|\
| * 9051a8b8 (feature-2) Commit D
|/
*   940c88e0 Merge feature-1 into feature
|\
| * 60dca27d (feature-1) Commit C
|/
* 8781f253 (main) Commit B
* 8704354e Initial commit
```

and

```
* 8a16a716 (HEAD -> main) Commit E
| *   1c3ae5de (feature) Merge feature-2 into feature
| |\
| | * 9051a8b8 (feature-2) Commit D
| |/
| * 940c88e0 Merge feature-1 into feature
|/|
| * 60dca27d (feature-1) Commit C
|/
* 8781f253 Commit B
* 8704354e Initial commit
```

In the first rendering, we have checked out `feature`, so we start with `feature`, and we don't come to `main` until we reach Commit B, after which both `feature` and `feature-1` are branched from it and then merge (reading upwards).

But in the second rendering, we have checked out `main`, so its commits are drawn in a single column down the left side. At Commit B, we still have to draw two branches, `feature` and `feature-1`, who have Commit B as their parent. So we need two `/` emerging from Commit B. But there isn't room for that any longer, so the second `/` is attached higher up; it *still* means exactly the same thing as the previous diagram, i.e. that 940c88e0 has Commit B as its parent. It's just a way of drawing.

Once again, if you find this disturbing, you might be happier using `gitk` or a GUI that stands a chance of making a more sophisticated drawing. `--graph` is a pretty crude way of drawing!