# How to achieve "first-parent" merge in git?

Tags: git, github

I am curious about how merging is done to the git repository on GitHub. When I visit the commits page, I only see the "first-parent" commit as you would see using `git log --first-parent`.

[image: git's repo commit page]
[image: git log --oneline --graph]
[image: git log]
[image]

Where as on my own repo, which I perform the merge with `git merge --log --no-ff branch_name` always show both the merge commit and the commit itself.

[image: my repo commits page]
[image: my repo git log]

I can't seem to find any options on `git merge` that will allow that. Basically, I am looking for ways where when I call `git merge` it will only add the merge commit, instead of adding both the merge commit and the commit itself.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. You've shown two completely separate views of two seemingly completely separate repositories. What exactly is it that you're asking here. You ask "... that will allow that". What does the last "that" in that sentence signify?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, thanks for the comment, I have updated the question a little. But what I am asking is, how can I achieve something similar in the first screenshot (git's repo) where the commits page is only showing the `merge commits` as compared to the second screenshots (my repo) which show both the merge commit and the individual commit.

Answer (score 1):

First, what GitHub shows is only an interface, and it is not Git's interface. So please try this: `git fetch` and now just say `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` and see what actually happened.

If *now* you see that there really is only one parent of this commit, that shows that this was never a merge commit to begin with: GitHub lets you merge pull requests using Squash or Rebase instead of a true merge, so there is indeed only one parent.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have added more screenshots to the question particularly showing the `git log --oneline --graph` and `git log`. It seems to me that commit has two parents and it's a true merge? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. You've totally proved that this is a true merge. So there's your answer: the "problem" is merely an artifact of the way GitHub shows you the commits. So ignore that and do what we just did: to find out what's up, fetch and use Git on your computer.

Comment: I thought it is just GitHub initially, but when I actually go and clone the repo down I am seeing the same thing. Calling just `git log` without the `--first-parent` option is showing only the merge commit, which is not the case in my own repo. However, when I do `git log --graph` it somehow show the commit added in the branch. Sorry if I am like going down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Cool but now you are just talking about the funny way in which `git log` works if you don't give it further instructions — and you've moved off the topic of your original question. It is perfectly possible that this is an xy question and you didn't really ask the question to which you wanted to know the answer. But that's all water under the bridge now. You asked the question you asked, so that is what I answered.

Comment: Fine discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71912490/341994